# Bringing the Android (NFC) TAG project to work

Tags: android, tags, guava, nfc

Used Android Project:[Tag](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Tag.git;a=summary)

After copying the Tag project into your workbench you should import the guava lib, to solve most of the errors. The Nullable errors can be fixed by importing the jsr305-1.3.9.jar regarding [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800033/guava-r07-gwt-and-javax-annotation-nullable)

After fixing all Error Messages I am trying to install the Tag App on my Nexus S, but I get the error message:

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Logcat Message:

> Can't install because provider name com.android.apps.tag (in package 
>   com.android.apps.tag) is already used by com.google.android.tag
>
> Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.android.apps.tag-1.apk

I think I get this message, because another version of Tags is already installed which couldn´t be removed via "Manage apps".

I hope that we can bring the android Tags App to work, so everyone has a foundation for building nfc Apps. I have already tried the sample NFC Demo "FakeTagsActivity", but this is another story.

Has anyone a idea how I can install this app?

Best regards

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Custom nexus S rom without the com.android.apps.tag application installed should do the trick, OR have you just thought of changing the app package to com.mytestapps.apps.tag for example?

Comment: Renaming the app package didn´t help.how can custom nexus S rom without the com.android.apps.tag application

Answer (score 0):

The NFC Research Lab Hagenberg, we are also testing the new NFC API for Nexus S. For easier use they've recompiled the SDK including the (un-)hidden NFC API. [Link to the discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f9e487e507b19b6)