# Cannot load classes from Guava r08 running in Tomcat. Cannot compile from source. Missing javax.annotations

Tags: java, richfaces, guava

I'm trying to use RichFaces in my learning JSF application. I have set up Maven using

```
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/
```

I have included the dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This has fetched guava-r08.jar.

When I try to run the project in Tomcat7 I see a lot of class load exceptions - failing to load classes that I can see exist within guava-r08.jar along with sac-1.3 and cssparser-0.9.5.

If I try to use the source instead - taking source from guava-r09 - Eclipse tells me that it cannot find classes such as javax.annotation.Nullable. Problem is neither can I!

Where can I find these classes, or am I taking the wrong approach from the start?

Thanks

- Richard

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guava r07, GWT and javax.annotation.Nullable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800033/guava-r07-gwt-and-javax-annotation-nullable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Maven configuration for RichFaces dependencies

Tomcat fails to load these classes, because RichFaces' dependency on Guava has a **runtime** scope. Contrary to the **compile** scope, these dependencies are not added to the classpath when compiling. You must include them yourself.

To achieve this, you should include [richfaces-bom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/richfaces/richfaces-bom/4.0.0.Final/richfaces-bom-4.0.0.Final.pom) in the dependency management section of your POM, as explained [in this JBoss wiki article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToMavenBasedProject). This will include Guava and all other required dependencies RichFaces might need.

This is the "Bill of Materials" (BOM) pattern. [The JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToMavenBasedProject) explains this pattern far better than I would, and links to other articles on the subject.

---

### `javax.annotation.Nullable` warnings in the Guava source

These occur because Guava uses [JSR 305 annotations](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/06/jsr-305-update). It is not required to depend on the JSR 305 jar when using Guava, because annotations do not require to be present on the classpath once compiled. Of course, if you want to use `@Nullable` and other such annotations in your code (you definitely should), you'll need to add a [dependency on the JSR 305 jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe the original reason I was unable to load the classes at runtime was that my Tomcat installation was running against an old JRE which did not recognise the modern JAR files. That dependency is very useful though, especially given that RichFaces advertises compatibility with it so giving the chance for end-to-end declaration of validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

I have started from scratch using instructions at [jboss.org](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Creating_a_project_with_Maven)

- I installed Maven 3.0.3
- I copied the supplied settings.xml to my .m2 directory and added the JBOSS section from [1](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Creating_a_project_with_Maven)
- I used the command line to create the project:

  mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.richfaces.archetypes \
                             -DarchetypeArtifactId=richfaces-archetype-simpleapp \
                             -DarchetypeVersion=4.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
                             -DgroupId=uk.m0rjc \
                             -DartifactId=jsfplay
- I then built the project. I had to remove the previously downloaded guava jars from my m2 repository because they were corrupt - perhaps my initial problem.

  mvn clean package
- I copied the WAR file it produced to Tomcat and navigated to the sample page at localhost:8080/jsfplay-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

I had some issues making the project work in Eclipse. These may be due to my setup from previous experiments.

- I used the "Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project" to import it
- I had to switch the project to JDK 1.6 and 1.6 compatibility mode.
- I was unable to use the JavaServer Faces facet. This does not seem to matter.
- I had to set my Server Profile to use the right JDK
- I had to map *.xhtml to the Faces Servlet in web.xml. It may have been corrupted when I pressed a wrong button to accept a JSF addin.

Then it worked!!

Now to try porting my existing code to the new project.